# Is it possible to cast entire map or array of object pointers from subclass to base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a map of object pointers of type Foo. Foo is a subclass of Bar. I would like to pass this map to a function whose signature requires a map with Bar function pointers. Is it possible to convert the map of Foo objects to Bar objects without copying each pointer in the original map to a new map via a for loop and `static_cast()`?

Passing a Foo object to a function that expects a Bar is implicitly converted to Bar, but seems the implicit conversion doesn't work for templated types.

Thanks for any help!

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Bar
{
public:
     int count=10;
};

class Foo: public Bar
{
public:
     int getCount()
     {
          return count;
     }
};

void mapFunc(std::map<std::string, Bar*>*)
     {
          //do something with Bar
     }

int main()
{

std::map<std::string, Foo*> fooMap;

fooMap.emplace("key", new Foo());

printf("Key is %i",fooMap["key"]->getCount());

mapFunc(&fooMap); //error (1)

return 0;
}
```

Error (1): `main.cpp:33:16: error: cannot convert ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Foo*>*’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Bar*>*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void mapFunc(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Bar*>*)’`

Comment: is there a particular reason why you want to have 'map<Foo*>'?  You are tagging polymorphism, but you are not using it here. I would think that you only need maps with '<Bar*>'  and use those pointers in a polymorphic manner to access members in Foo.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to convert the map of Foo objects to Bar objects without copying each pointer in the original map to a new map via a for loop and `static_cast()`?*"

`std::map<std::string, Foo*>` and `std::map<std::string, Bar*>` are separate and unrelated types, so you can't safely cast one directly to the other.

A converting loop is the safest option, especially if you ever change your `Foo*` map to use `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to avoid the memory leak that your example currently has, eg:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Bar
{
public:
    int count = 10;
};

class Foo: public Bar
{
public:
    int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
};

void mapFunc(std::map<std::string, Bar*> *m)
{
    // do something with Bar elements...
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> fooMap;

    fooMap.emplace("key", std::make_unique<Foo>());

    std::cout << "Key is " << fooMap["key"]->getCount();

    std::map<std::string, Bar*> barMap;
    for (auto &elem : fooMap)
        barMap.emplace(elem.first, elem.second.get());

    mapFunc(&barMap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strict aliasing isn't really the problem here, though I guess that's being picky.

Comment: (Personally, I'd rewrite `mapFunc` to like not take a map)

Answer (score -3):

No, You couldn't violate the rules, you should use an pointer to pass this or could use some methods